# Add offer product programmatically in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I added product with 0 price as a offer product in observer. My code is

```
 public function addOfferProduct($observer)
     {
        $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        $items = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParams();
        if($items['offer'])
        {
           try
           {
               $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($items['offer']);
               $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
               $quoteItem = $quote->addProduct($product, $qty); 
               $quoteItem->setCustomPrice(0);
               // we need this since Magento 1.4
               $quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice(0);
               $quote->collectTotals()->save(); 
           }
           catch(Exception $e)
           {
               //echo $e->getMessage();;
           }

       }
    }
```

In Cart page the added product looks like separate product with 0 Price. I want to add that product as a offer product like bundle product style.